# How to download IMF Data Through JSON in R

Tags: json, r, database, api

I recently took an interest in retrieving data in R through JSON. Specifically, I want to be able to access data through the IMF. I know virtually nothing about JSON so I will share what I [think I] know so far, and what I have accomplished.

I browsed their web page for JSON, which helped a little bit. It gave me the start point URL. Here is the web page; `http://datahelp.imf.org/knowledgebase/articles/667681-using-json-restful-web-service`

I managed to download (using the `GET()` and the `fromJSON()` functions) some lists, which are really bulky. I know enough about the lists that the "call" was successful, but I cannot for the life of me get actual data. So far, I have been trying to use the `rawToChar()` function on the "content" data but I am virtually stuck there.

If anything, I managed to create data frames that contain the codes, which I presume would be used somewhere in the JSON link. Here is what I have.

```
      all.imf.data = fromJSON("http://dataservices.imf.org/REST/SDMX_JSON.svc/Dataflow/")
      str(all.imf.data)

      #all.imf.data$Structure$Dataflows$Dataflow$Name[[2]] #for the catalogue of sources
      catalogue1 = cbind(all.imf.data$Structure$Dataflows$Dataflow$KeyFamilyRef,
                                    all.imf.data$Structure$Dataflows$Dataflow$Name[[2]])
      catalogue1 = catalogue1[,-2] # catalogue of all the countries


      data.structure = fromJSON("http://dataservices.imf.org/REST/SDMX_JSON.svc/DataStructure/IFS")
      info1 = data.frame(data.structure$Structure$Concepts$ConceptScheme$Concept[,c(1,4)])
      View(data.structure$Structure$CodeLists$CodeList$Description)
      str(data.structure$Structure$CodeLists$CodeList$Code)

                #Units
                units = data.structure$Structure$CodeLists$CodeList$Code[[1]]

                #Countries
                countries = data.frame(data.structure$Structure$CodeLists$CodeList$Code[[3]])
                countries = countries[,-length(countries)]


                #Series Codes
                codes = data.frame(data.structure$Structure$CodeLists$CodeList$Code[[4]])
                codes = codes[,-length(codes)]

# all.imf.data   # JSON from the starting point, provided on the website
# catalogue1     # data frame of all the data bases, International Financial Statistics, Government Financial Statistics, etc.
# codes          # codes for the specific data sets (GDP, Current Account, etc).
# countries      # data frame of all the countries and their ISO codes
# data.structure # large list, with starting URL and endpoint "IFS". Ideally, I want to find some data set somewhere within this data base.  
"info1"         # looks like parameters for retrieving the data (for instance, dates, units, etc).

# units         # data frame that indicates the options for units
```

I would just like some advice about how to go about retrieving any data, something as simple as GDP (PPP) for a constant year. I have been following an article in R blogs (which retrieved data in the EU's database) but I cannot replicate the procedure for the IMF. I feel like I am close to retrieving something useful but I cannot quite get there. Given that I have data frames that contain the names for the databases, the series and the codes for the series, I think it is just a matter of figuring out how to construct the appropriate URL for getting the data, but I could be wrong.

Provided in the data frame `codes` are the codes for the data sets I presume. Is there a way to make a call for the data for, let's say, the US for `BK_DB_BP6_USD`, which is "Balance of Payments, Capital Account, Total, Debit, etc"? How should I go about doing this in the context of R?

Comment: Perhaps just use the API and try learning JSON on a less complex data source. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/IMFData/index.html — OR — read the source code for the existing API pkg.

Comment: Oh yes! I'm aware of that package! Thanks. However, given that many websites share info through JSON, I figured that going through this exercise would be useful for me

Comment: Use a less complex site and/or read the source code.